# Java sqlite jdbc и другое

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, jar

Собрал в `jar` проект, который работает с файлами `sqlite` (выполняется просто запрос `"select id from user"`). На компьютере, где все собирал, все прекрасно работает. Скидываю `jar` на флэшку и пробую тестировать на соседнем компьютере - ничего не работает. Исключения не выбрасываются. Собирал с помощью `maven`, через `maven-shade-plugin`. Запускал в командной строке `java -jar SmplSql.jar`.

```
try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/1/MyDataBase";
            System.out.println(url);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка соединения\n" + e);
        }
        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select id from user");
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                System.out.println(id);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка выборки\n" + e);
        }
```

Comment: « - ничего не работает» недостаточно — нужно точнее описать что именно происходит. Код прекращает работу или зависает? На какой строке? В консоль что-нибудь выводится?

Comment: в консоль выводится строка с url ом. Дальше ничего: ни результата, ни исключений.

Comment: Программа завершается или висит в командной строке? Попробуйте добавить отладочный вывод после каждой строки (например, `System.out.println("connection = DriverManager");`) и посмотреть на какой строке выполнение останавливается.

Comment: Файл пустой мб подставили?

Comment: Файл не пустой.

Comment: Файл пустой, извените за дизинформацию.